# SQL: Putting condition on result of an aggregate function

Tags: php, mysql

This works fine:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.ascii_name, COUNT(*) AS nr
    FROM cities c 
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON (j.city_id = c.id ) 
    WHERE j.is_active = 1 
    GROUP BY c.name
limit 100
```

but when I want to put the condition on th new column nr it says column not found

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.ascii_name, COUNT(*) AS nr
    FROM cities c 
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON (j.city_id = c.id ) 
    WHERE j.is_active = 1 and nr > 100
    GROUP BY c.name
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: please explain what type of error you are getting..?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should put the condition on nr in the HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.ascii_name, COUNT(*) AS nr
    FROM cities c 
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON (j.city_id = c.id ) 
    WHERE j.is_active = 1
    GROUP BY c.name
    HAVING nr > 100
limit 100
```

This is because nr is the result of an aggregate function (COUNT(*)) and as such is not available at the time the WHERE filter is applied.

EDIT: in some database servers, the reference to nr doesn't work; you can also use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 100`.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your statement should read

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.ascii_name, COUNT(*) AS nr
             FROM cities c 
             INNER JOIN jobs j ON (j.city_id = c.id ) 
             WHERE j.is_active = 1
             GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c.id, c.name, c.ascii_name, COUNT(*) AS nr
    FROM cities c 
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON (j.city_id = c.id ) 
    WHERE j.is_active = 1 and nr.c.id > 100
    GROUP BY c.name
limit 100